Error while running pest --parallel in CircleCI with PHP 8.2
I'm facing an issue while running pest --parallel inside a CircleCI pipeline. My project is using PHP 8.2 and the latest version of Pest testing framework. When I try to execute the tests with the pest --parallel command, I encounter the following error:

Here are the steps I took to set up my CircleCI pipeline:

I configured the CircleCI environment to use PHP 8.2 using custom dockerfile
My pipeline is using the pest --parallel command to run the tests in parallel.

I verified the same tests work locally outside CircleCI.
Has anyone else experienced this issue, or does anyone have any suggestions on how to resolve it? Any help would be greatly appreciated!
